# Open Python IDLE in current virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, cmd, virtualenv, python-idle

Using the Windows command line, how can I open a Python file inside the current virtual environment that I am in?

For example, say I'm in my virtual environment:

```
(env) C:\MyFolder>
```

and then I want to open my Python file:

```
(env) C:\MyFolder>mypythonfile.py
```

The .py file will open in IDLE but not inside the (env) environment

Comment: You have to open it with python, it can't open without any program. So type python mypythonfile.py.

Comment: When I enter `file.py` in Command Prompt, it runs the file rather than opening it in an IDLE editor.  Maybe you customized your file associations.  If `python` runs some version of 3.x, `python -m idlelib file.py` will open it in an IDLE editor, and I would expect the same within (env).

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this via 3 steps:

Suppose that you are using windows system and have open a cmd window.

1. Activate your virtual environment:
   **venv/Scripts/activate**  (venv is the path of your virtual environemnt)

*You could use this command "where python" to check if your virtual environment is activated. If success, it should point to your virtual environment path at the first line.*

2. Launch idle within your virtual environment:
   **python -m idlelib.idle**

*A IDLE window should be popped up. You can check if this is within the virtual environment by import a package only installed in the virtual environment but not in the local python.*

3. Now from the idle open the file that you want to edit:
   **Click 'File - Open' in sequence, and then choose the file.**

*Now you can just try to press 'F5', you will see this file would be run in the virtual idle.*